# Setting initial assignments for mixed-membership stochastic blockmodel

Tags: r, graph-theory, topic-models, networks, igraph

I created two networks at two points (in the middle of the month and at the end of the month). Tried to run *mmsb.collapsed.gibbs.sampler* for the first network and obtained network communities. However, now I'm trying to run MMSB for the second network with initial assignments from the first network. What I tried is something like this:

```
net1.assignments <- split(network1.mmsb$net.assignments.right, rep(1:ncol(network1.mmsb$net.assignments.right), each = nrow(network1.mmsb$net.assignments.right)))

network2.mmsb <- mmsb.collapsed.gibbs.sampler(network2.adj.matrix,
                 K = 20, 
                 initial = list(assignments = net1.assignments),
                 num.iterations=100,
                 alpha = 0.1,
                 burnin = 20L,
                 beta.prior = list(1, diag(5, 3) + 1))
```

Running simply MMSB for the second network without setting initial parameter works just fine. But, when I try to assign initials as above, the error I'm getting is

> Error in structure(.Call("collapsedGibbsSampler", documents,
>   as.integer(K),  : initial_d must be a length nw Integer.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

**EDIT**

I've been trying different options to make this work. But, I'm still getting this error:

> ```
> Error in structure(.Call("collapsedGibbsSampler", documents, as.integer(K),  : 
>   initial_d must be a length nw Integer.
> ```

Or this one:

> ```
> Error in structure(.Call("collapsedGibbsSampler", documents, as.integer(K),  : 
>   initial must be a length nd NewList.
> ```

This depends whether I'm assigning `network1.mmsb$net.assignments.right` or `net1.assignments` from the example above.

Why?

Well, the documentation says:

> ***initial*** - A list of initial topic assignments for words. It should be in
>   the same format as the *assignments* field of the return value. If this
>   field is NULL, then the sampler will be initialized with random
>   assignments.

On the other hand, *assignments* are defined as:

> A list of length D. Each element of the list, say
>   assignments[[i]] is an integer vector of the same length as the number
>   of columns in documents[[i]] indicating the topic assignment for each
>   word.

If I'm not mistaken, the number of documents in the case of MMSB should be the number of nodes. That means that the length of *assignments* should be equal to the **number of nodes**, which is further equal to:

```
dim(network2.adj.matrix)[1]
```

This further means that `net1.assignments` should be the input for `initial`, where `net1.assignments` is the list of vectors, where the length of each vector is equal to the number of nodes. Also, a length of the `net1.assignments` is equal to the number of nodes. In that case the error is

> initial_d must be a length nw Integer

which doesn't make sense since `int nw = INTEGER(GET_DIM(document))[1];` (and why output says nw instead of the value?!), and `GET_DIM(document)` should be equal to the number of nodes.

But, if I assign `network1.mmsb$net.assignments.right`, the error becomes:

> initial must be a length nd NewList

This I also don't understand since this would be a length of the adjacency matrix (which is the input for mmsb) and should be the same (and it is the same in this case) as `network1.mmsb$net.assignments.right`. And again, why `nd` instead of the value?!